# Move files to folders with partial names

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have about 250 files that I need to move to a specific folder. The problem is that folder only have the partial name of the files.

For example, I need to move file "12345.txt" to folder "12345 - hello" as each folder starts by the actual file name.

Can I do this in a batch file in DOS?

Thank you.

Comment: *Really* DOS? Where did you get long file names there?

Comment: Do the folders' names have a regular structure, i.e. "filename - something" like in your example? Is the following situation possible: filename "a.txt", first folder "a000", second folder "a111", i.e. can the matching be ambiguous?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming Windows, it's actually not hard:

```
@echo off
rem loop over all files
for %%f in (*) do call :process "%%f"

rem this is necessary to avoid running the subroutine below
rem after the loop above ended
goto :eof

rem subroutine that gets called for every file
rem this finds the first matching folder and moves the file there
:process
rem the /d loops over all directories - the mask ensures that
rem the directory name starts with the given file name (without
rem extension)
for /d %%d in ("%~n1*") do (
    echo Moving "%~1" to "%%d" ...
    move "%~1" "%%d"
    rem Return since the file was moved already
    goto :EOF
)
```

Can also be found in [my SVN repository](http://svn.lando.us/joey/Public/SO/3181953).

Comment: thank you Johannes. it worked. thank you, trully appreciated.