# Move files based on partial name - DOS/Batch

Tags: file, batch-file, automation, dos

I have this code

```
pushd "C:\Folders\"
for %%j in (*) do (
md "%%~nj"
move "%%j" "%%~nj"
)
popd
pause
exit
```

This move files with the same name into a folder with the same name, if the folder does not exist it will create a new folder. Ok great.

This issue I have is that I want the same function as above however I only was it to look at the first 4 characters. E.g.

```
1234 - sample.jpg
1234 - sample-sm.jpg
1234 - sample-new.jpg
1234 - sample-right.jpg

1235 - sample.jpg
```

1234 files will be moved to the same folder as the first 4 characters are the same, however 1235 will be moved to a new folder because the fist for characters are different.

Thank you

---

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd "C:\Folders\"
for %%a in (*) do (
  set fldr=%%~na
  set fldr=!fldr:~0,4!
  md "!fldr!"
  move "%%a" "!fldr!"
)
popd
pause
exit
```

However it creates new folders with the first 4 letters and moves the files to these created folders... It does move everything with the same first 4 letters to the correct folder.

So no I need it NO to make a directory but to move it to the already create directory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [move files to folders with partial names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181953/move-files-to-folders-with-partial-names)

Comment: i might have overlooked something but it does not seem to me they are the same question. OP wants a way to create a folder with a name that shortens the filename; while the former SO question was about finding an existing folder with a name match.

Comment: I think you are right but I do not thing you have have both functions. If the folder exists (which it will) I need the all files with the SAME fist 4 chars to be moved into that folder. e.g.

Comment: Also, I have seen Andriy M code however the files name have to be all the same... Only the first portion of my are the same. I have tested the code. I just need it to look at the fist 4 chars and move them to a pre created folder with the same first 4 chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read `HELP SET` and then try the following code as an starting point to build your solution...

you will need to cope with duplicated names that may occur.

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*) do (
  set fldr=%%~na
  set fldr=!fldr:~0,4!
  echo md "!fldr!"
  echo move "%%a" "!fldr!"
)
```

try it, test extensively and remove the `ECHO` commands.

Comment: Thank you PA. just need a little bit more help, I have been testing :)